# Subquery is not identifying column of main query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Error is

"Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'nt.id' in 'where clause'"

This the query

```
SELECT
  nt.from as 'SENDER EMP ID',
  if(nt.notification_time IS NOT NULL, nt.notification_time, nt.notification_start_time) as 'NOTIFICATION TIME',
  nt.delivery_type as 'NOTIFICATION TYPE',
  eh.first_name as 'SENDER FIRST NAME',
  eh.last_name as 'SENDER LAST NAME',
  eh.site_name as 'SENDER SITE NAME',
  nt.title as 'NOTIFICATION TITLE',
  nt.body as 'NOTIFICATION BODY',
  (
    select count(DISTINCT notifiable_id)
    from notifications.notifications
    where nt.id = notifications.notification_template_id
  ) as SEND TO No. OF USERS,
  (
    select GROUP_CONCAT('\n', counts_per_desig ) as counts
    from
    (
      select
        concat (if(quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation, quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation, "Un Assigned"), " : ", count(*) ) as counts_per_desig
      from notifications.notifications
      LEFT JOIN quartz.employee_hierarchy ON quartz.employee_hierarchy.employee_id = notifications.notifications.notifiable_id
      where notifications.notifications.notification_template_id  = nt.id
        AND notifications.read_at IS NOT NULL
      Group By quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation
    ) as 'READ BY No. OF USERS'
  )
FROM notifications.notification_template AS nt
LEFT JOIN quartz.employee_hierarchy as eh ON eh.employee_id = nt.from
where (nt.created_by_type = 1)
  and eh.location_id in (22, 123, 332)
  and nt.from not in (185994, 81016, 168090, 24799, 104967)
```

There is a problem in this portion so code (subquery)

```
select GROUP_CONCAT('\n',counts_per_desig ) as counts
from
(
  select concat (if(quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation,quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation,"Un Assigned")," : ",count(*) ) as counts_per_desig
  from notifications.notifications
  LEFT JOIN quartz.employee_hierarchy ON quartz.employee_hierarchy.employee_id = notifications.notifications.notifiable_id
  where notifications.notifications.notification_template_id  = 123
    AND notifications.read_at IS NOT NULL
  Group By quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation
) as 'READ BY No. OF USERS'
```

Comment: On a side note: Single quotes are delimiters for string literals, not for names. In MySQL you can use backticks for names, but it's often the best choice to go completely without them and use names that make no problems instead, e.g. `read_by_number_of_users`.

Comment: Another side note: Replacing a null with another value is usually done with `COALESCE`. So `if(nt.notification_time IS NOT NULL, nt.notification_time, nt.notification_start_time) as 'NOTIFICATION TIME'` becomes `COALESCE(nt.notification_time nt.notification_start_time) as evaluated_notification_time`.

Comment: Another side note: `if(quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation, ...`? You are treating the designation column as a boolean here. If it's a string you should compare it with something in order not to get unexpected results here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are one level too deep. Unfortunately it is not possible to access a column name in a sub sub query.

You must hence move the join criteria (the notification template ID) one level up. Change:

```
(
  select GROUP_CONCAT('\n', counts_per_desig ) as counts
  from
  (
    select
      concat (if(quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation, quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation, "Un Assigned"), " : ", count(*) ) as counts_per_desig
    from notifications.notifications
    LEFT JOIN quartz.employee_hierarchy ON quartz.employee_hierarchy.employee_id = notifications.notifications.notifiable_id
    where notifications.notifications.notification_template_id  = nt.id
      AND notifications.read_at IS NOT NULL
    Group By quartz.employee_hierarchy.designation
  ) as 'READ BY No. OF USERS'
)
```

to

```
(
  select group_concat('\n', counts_per_desig)
  from
  (
    select
      n.notification_template_id,
      concat(coalesce(ne.designation, 'unassigned'), ' : ', count(*)) as counts_per_desig
    from notifications.notifications n
    left join quartz.employee_hierarchy ne on ne.employee_id = n.notifiable_id
    where n.read_at is not null
    group by n.notification_template_id, ne.designation
  ) designations
  where designations.notification_template_id = nt.id
) as read_by_no_of_users
```

Comment: Can't use count(*) with GROUP_CONCAT also even if I remove count(*) it is returning multiple rows which is giving "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: You are right. I am sorry. I have corrected my answer. Please also see the notes I made under your request.